# logrotate not executed automatically

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, logrotate

i am working with docker, with an ubuntu image (16.04.3 LTS)

in /var/log/syslog i see that :

```
(root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
```

So, i suppose that the daily.cron is correctly executed

in /etc/logrotate.conf, i have this :

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root root

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

So, because there is "include /etc/logrotate.d", logrotate should be executed no ?

in /etc/logrotate.d/ i have my file :

```
/var/www/my-app/app/logs/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 20
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 644 www-data
    dateext
    sharedscripts
}
```

But, my files are not rotated automatically

I i manually run this command, it works :

```
logrotate -f  /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the status file at `/var/lib/logrotate/status`? If the log files you want to rotate have a timestamp from today (for example from running `logrotate -f`), they won't be rotated on the same calendar day.

Comment: i have no file in /var/lib/logrotate
When i create a file "test.log" in "/var/www/my-app/app/logs/" anf if i run "logrotate -f", the file is rotated. like i said, it is not launched "automaticaly"

Comment: logrotate has to keep track of rotated files somewhere. My Ubuntu 16.04 has that file at `/var/lib/logrotate/status`, but if it's elsewhere, the logrotate man page should tell you where. Is logrotate in your `/etc/cron.daily` directory?

Comment: Yes i have it in /etc/cron.daily/ with -rwxr-xr-x rigths

Comment: And the other logs (`/var/log/btmp` and `/var/log/wtmp`) do get rotated? Do you see the daily cron in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Logrotate files are not included in Ubuntu docker image. Which steps did you follow to make it available? This might be related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113677/docker-image-ubuntu16-04-seems-to-omit-some-files-for-logrotate