# docker image ubuntu:16.04 seems to omit some files for logrotate

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, logrotate

I built an image based on `ubuntu:16.04`. While building the image I did run some commands including `apt-get -y update`.

Then, I browse the image by `docker run -it myimage bash` and I found there are some omitted files for `logrotate` in there comparing to normal `ubuntu16.04` OS.

For instance, `/etc/logrotate.conf`, `/usr/sbin/logrotate`, `/var/lib/logrotate/status`.

I could't find them anywhere even with running `find / -name logrotate*`. the `find` command only show`/etc/logrotate.d`(`/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` also exist).
Seeing trances of logrotate like `logrotate.d`, I assume logrotate must exist in there.

However, why it doesn't have not only those files but even also executable? 
I want them because I want to try [it(How can I monitor what logrotate is doing)](https://serverfault.com/questions/189320/how-can-i-monitor-what-logrotate-is-doing)

How could I make it with the ubuntu16:04 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Each container should have only one concern](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern) (I.e: no services, no daemons, no additional tools). Having that in mind, it make sense for logrotate configuration files to be omitted, since **logrotate daemon is not there**.

Alternatives to manage logs on containers could be using shared volumes (logrotate could then run on the host) ([an example of that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-docker-data-volumes-on-ubuntu-14-04)) or delegating to [docker logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/).